# Kotlin default arguments: forbid zero arguments calls

Tags: syntax, kotlin

In my project I have a function like this:

```
fun doCoolStuff(arg1: Int = 0, arg2: String? = null) {
}
```

Which I want it to use it in following cases:

```
obj.doCoolStuff(101) // only first argument provided
obj.doCoolStuff("102") // only second argument provided
obj.doCoolStuff(103, "104") // both arguments provided
```

But not in this one:

```
obj.doCoolStuff() // illegal case, should not be able to call the function like this
```

How do I achieve this on the syntax level?

Comment: On the second thought - should I just create a bunch of overloaded functions (three, actually) plus a private function which will actually do the cool stuff? 
I hope there's something more concise in kotlin.

Comment: You can have a check inside the method for if both are set, but what kind of situation do you have where the defaults cannot be used together?

Comment: The other way round - the function shouldn't be called with no arguments. 
The way I do it now, is by throwing the exception when no arguments provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no syntax in Kotlin that would allow you to accomplish what you need. Use overloaded functions (I'd use two, one for each required argument):

```
fun doCoolStuff(arg1: Int, arg2: String? = null) { ... }
fun doCoolStuff(arg2: String?) { doCoolStuff(defaultIntValue(), arg2) }
```

Comment: I have a case when I need to call the function with both arguments provided, I guess that's cannot be done with just two functions?

Comment: It works... but it's not very glanceable. I have to stop and read it careful to understand it's offering all 3 variants (int-only, int & string => overload 1; string-only => overload 2).

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible because you made both arguments optional. You could add a check in the method body or, what I'd prefer, provide proper **overloads**:

```
fun doCoolStuff(arg1: Int) {
    doCoolStuff(arg1, null)
}

fun doCoolStuff(arg2: String?) {
    doCoolStuff(0, arg2)
}

fun doCoolStuff(arg1: Int, arg2: String?) {}
```

Comment: If the 3rd overload had a default value of null for the String param you could remove the 1st overload... Though I actually think your code is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `doCoolStuff()` with zero parameter and mark it as deprecated with [`DeprecationLevel.ERROR`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecation-level/-e-r-r-o-r.html).

```
fun doCoolStuff(arg1: Int = 0, arg2: String? = null) {}

@Deprecated("Should be called with at least one parameter", level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
fun doCoolStuff() {}
```

Comment: Sorry, the idea to declare _new_ methods with Deprecated isn't appealing to me :) On the other hand, it would add a nice self-explainable warning in Android Studio...

Comment: @AlexeyGorovoy It produces compile-time error instead of simply warning.

Answer (score 0):

Might be I don't understand but this works for me

```
fun doCoolStuff() {
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Can't do this")
}
```

Just define the method with no parameters and throw exception.

Comment: This would only happen at runtime which is bad. Doing it like s1m0nw1 would already give an error at compile time.

Comment: I would argue if this approach "bad" - it probably depends on the context in which function is called. Anyway, I use this approach now and posted the question to try to find a better solution.